# sqlite3 can't loading extension

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to load an extension in sqlite3.

I managed to compile the extension using:

```bash
clang -bundle -fPIC -Isqlite3 -o <desired extension name>.sqlext <filename>.c
```

However, I cannot seem to load the extension.
`.load <path to extension file>`

`Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "load". Enter ".help" for help`

And when I type `.help`, I cannot see `.load`.

I have also tried to enable extensions.

```cpp
int sqlite3_enable_load_extension(sqlite3 *db, int onoff==1);
```

`Error: near "int": syntax error`

I would really appreciate a step-by-step instruction on how to enable extensions in SQLite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your sqlite compiled with [SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_load_extension). Get the one build without this flag, or build it yourself.

You cannot use `sqlite3_enable_load_extension` from SQL, it is sqlite's C API.

Answer (score 0):

For many vendors, the default provided `sqlite3` does not have a load extension enabled. (keltar clarified)

> I would really appreciate a step-by-step instruction on how to enable extensions in SQLite?

- Go to [Sqlite Downloads](https://sqlite.org/download.html)
- Get the appropriate build. It has the `load` extension enabled.
- Use it directly or replace `/usr/bin/sqlite3` with the newer one.